# Is migration required from swift 2 to swift 2.1?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

Xcode 7.1 is now available on app store but before I update xcode I need to be sure that my existing project won't breakdown because of the update. So would updating from xcode 7 to 7.1 run the migration assistant for swift 2 and breakdown my project?

Comment: The Swift Programming Lanugauge [revision history](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/RevisionHistory.html) can also be useful to see what might affect a project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that there weren't any breaking syntax changes.  Mostly just quality of life updates for the language (being able to put string literals in string interpolation statements, function covariance/contravariance, etc).

Comment: It's true.. no migration required :)